# Comparing JSON-typed column with specific string value

Tags: sql, mysql, json, mysql-json

I have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id     int, 
    name   varchar(255), 
    data   json
);
```

| id | name | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | ["a", "b"] |
| 2 | Pete | ["a", "b", "c"] |
| 3 | Mike | ["a", "b"] |

Where column `data` has `JSON` type, and I want to select rows where field `data` equal to string `["a", "b"]`.

Naive approach I'm currently using:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE data = '["a", "b"]'
```

Yet it always returns empty set. What is right way to compare JSON fields with strings?

Comment: What is the version of your MySQL and can you please add your table structure definition?

Comment: You're trying to compare a json datatype with a string, that's why the result is empty. To solve it, you either need a function that returns a json, or use a cast.

Comment: MySQL version is 8.0.33.

Table definition:
`CREATE TABLE mytable (id int, name varchar(255), data json)`

P. S; Sorry, I can't add this to question, stackoverflow show me "not properly formatted code" error even If I'm just trying to save question without adding any text to it.

Comment: BTW, do you also want `["b", "a"]` to match?

Comment: No, I want only `["a", "b"]` to match. Ideally I just want to compare JSON column like if it was varchar column.

Comment: See barmars answer. You can't compare the string representations e.g. `["b", "a"]`, `["b","a"]` and `["\u0061", "\u0062"]` are all the same.

Comment: If you really want to compare strings, instead of dealing with jsons, you need to cast your json column to string (which although looks as an antipattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CAST(... AS JSON)` to convert the JSON-as-string to JSON data type for comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE data = CAST('[
  "a",
  "b"
]' AS JSON)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `JSON_ARRAY()` function to create a JSON array, and compare with this.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE data = JSON_ARRAY('a', 'b');
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6R2sRyYQLmJm219yUH3Vnd/0)